# Extract arduino collected data periodically

Tags: debugging

I'd like to extract data collected by a battery powered arduino for example once a day without stopping it and not using SD card.

It's posible, when I want to extract the collected data, to connect a laptop through the USB and then get data because Arduino is, at regulat time intervals, calling 'Serial.println(...)'?

Comment: What do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Please be aware thqt most Arduino models will reboot when you plug a cable to the USB port and have your PC open communication. This may not be what you want as all data stored in SRAM will be lost.

Comment: Would you consider having a second arduino to collect the data wirelessly? This second. Arduino could be connected to a computer collecting the data. Asking since I'm not sure if the solution absolutely can only include a single arduino.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit crude, but I think you could use an FTDI cable (which is a USB to UART converter) to have a program in your laptop talk to the Arduino using its UART (serial) interface.

To do it, you could plug the USB side of a FTDI serial cable to your laptop. The other end of the cable has a plug with 6 pins, 2 of which are the TX and RX serial signals. You could plug those two signals to pins D0 and D1 (RX & TX) of your Arduino using male-to-male jumpers.

In terms of software, you could code the Arduino sketch to listen on the serial port for a command from your laptop. When the command arrives, it would output the stored data (could be comma separated values with CR+LF as end of line). Your laptop would then listen for the answer and retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Depends how much data to have enough storage space. You also need consider potential memory endurance. E.g. external I2C ferromagnetic memory is good option. Of course it's not on Arduino board, you implement extension.